# Print awk function out to new line everytime

Tags: bash, scripting

part of my code is as below :

```
output=$(cat databaselog | awk '{print $9,$1,$2,$6}' )
echo $output >> savedfile
```

Output will be something like this , saved in a new file called savedfile

```
name1 date1 id1 ip1 name2 date2 id2 ip2 name3 date3 id3 ip3
```

But i want it to be like this:

```
name1 date1 id1 ip1
name2 date2 id2 ip2
name3 date3 id3 ip3
```

i know its quite easy , but i cant find the right way to do it , pls help thanks!

Comment: You should always quote your shell variables. Try `echo "$output" >> savedfile`...

Comment: Apart from the fact that you should be quoting `$output` in your call to `echo`, why are you even using that variable when you could just do `awk '{print $9,$1,$2,$6}' databaselog >>savedfile`?

Comment: thanks ! adding "" works !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to double-quote `$output` as `"$output"` when you echo it.  Otherwise the output will have newlines and other white-space transformed into just spaces.

It's also good practice to double-quote the command substitution.  `output="$(...)"` instead of just `output=$(...)`

e.g.

```bsh
output="$( cat databaselog | awk '{print $9,$1,$2,$6}' )"
echo >> savedfile
echo "$output" >> savedfile
```

But you'd be better off with just:

```
echo >> savedfile
awk '{print $9,$1,$2,$6}' databaselog >> savedfile
```

Comment: Interesting. I also thought that quoting the command substitution was necessary, but recently someone pointed out to me that this was not necessary in an immediate variable assignment (so quoting only the `$output` should be sufficient). Do you have an authoritative source on that?

Comment: Nope, no source.  Just habit and a vague recollection that it matters in some cases, and like anything involving shell quoting: "double-quote unless you know for sure that you want word-splitting to happen".  Also, one of the many advantages of `$()` over backticks is that not only can you nest the command substitutions, you can also nest the quoting in the different sub-shell levels.   Double-quoting `"$output"`  when using it (e.g. with the `echo`) is the crucial thing to avoid newlines etc being transformed into spaces.

Comment: one more question @cas , what if i want to have a spacing from the previous entry everytime when i do this >> savedfile,

Comment: @WenhanXiao do you mean an extra blank line?   just echo or printf it.  i'll edit my answer to show.

Comment: @cas big thanks mate ! sorry i am still new to all this

Comment: @cas hey buddy, any idea how to display .html files in console instead of firefox ?

Comment: use a text mode browser like `lynx` or `links`.   Or just cat or less if you want to see the raw html.   BTW, I know you're just trying to be friendly so I'm not offended, but I don't like being called buddy or mate or pal etc.  In Australia, words like that are aggressive fighting words unless they come from someone who's a good, known friend.